# Avoid redundant builds and tests in CI

Tags: maven, continuous-integration

I have little knowledge of CI. I have a hierarchy of dependent maven projects such as there are 3 projects - A, B and C. A has a dependency on B and B has a dependency on C. Is there a way where I can smartly detect which all projects to build and test depending on the commits happening in them. For example, if a change is made in C, do i have to build and test B and A everytime?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Jenkins jobs to build and trigger tests for each of the modules in a manner that accomplishes the need to run required tests :

For example :

1. One Jenkins job that polls on commits to Project "A" and trigger build for "A" and run its tests.
2. Another Jenkins job that polls on commits to Project "B" and trigger
   build for "B" and "A" and run tests for both "B" and "A"

Similar third one for "C". 
With commits to "C", it is required to test all the three, because they are dependent and any changes in "C" may break "A" as well.

Comment: Thanks @Nav. I have the same thoughts, I was wondering if there is a plugin in jenkins which can clear the "may break A" thing for me. Like, by doing some code analysis whether it is possible if i can build and test up the hierarchy only when it is required. I am learning CI and jenkins and am aware of only few basic plugins.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.